# Need Help In Token-22

Tags: spl-token, token-2022, spl

1. Suppose if we set transfer fee 0.5% can we update it too 1% after token mint?
2. How can we set specific owner wallet address to receive tax fee?

3- Can we put multiple tax fee for multiple wallet address like 0.5% for whitelist addresses and 1% for non-whitelisted?

4- How can we update tax fee wallet address from Wallet A to Wallet B?

5- How can we disable tax fee?

Please share spl-token command for each point.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the commands for these but I can give you some info:

1. Yes, as long as you are the transfer fee config authority.
2. The withdraw withheld authority must harvest the tokens from all accounts that have a withheld fee manually. When harvesting fees, you can choose which wallet you want to receive the fees.
3. You can't do this with the transfer fee extension. I believe you could with a transfer hooks if you implemented it. (Wouldn't recommend since transfer hooks aren't supported by most programs/DApps yet)
4. You can do this as long as you are the transfer fee config authority.
5. You can't enable/disable the extension but you can set the fee to 0 as long as you are the config authority.

I have built a free browser tool that takes care of all of this.

You can check it out if you want at:

https://capult.xyz/

You can create new tokens or add a token to the manager (all with zero platform fees) at:

https://capult.xyz/tools/manage/add

Answer (score 1):

To answer your questions:

1. To set the transfer fee:

```
spl-token set-transfer-fee <TOKEN_PUBKEY> <NEW_FEE_BASIS_POINTS> <NEW_MAXIMUM_FEE>
```

2. To set the withdraw withheld authority:

```
spl-token authorize <TOKEN_ADDRESS> withdraw-withheld <NEW_AUTHORITY>
```

3. No, but you can set the higher transfer fee and then create an off-chain bot that will refund some portion of the transfer fee based on previous transactions.
4. This question is the same as number 2. You don't set a wallet address, but rather an authority who can withdraw the withheld tokens from token accounts and the mint.
5. To set the fee to 0:

```
spl-token set-transfer-fee <TOKEN_PUBKEY> 0 0
```

And then after that, you can disable the transfer fee config:

```
spl-token authorize <TOKEN_PUBKEY> transfer-fee-config --disable
```